# How to store in the database directly the translation?

Tags: plugin-development, database, translation, activation

I would like to store my custom posts with the correct translation when the user activate the plugin.

```
$a_custom_post = array(
            'post_type'      => "foo-page",
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'post_title'     => __( 'Foo page name', PLUGIN_DOMAIN ),
            'post_content'   => "",
            'comment_status' => 'closed',
            'ping_status'    => 'closed',
            'post_author'    => 1,
            'guid'           => null
        );
wp_insert_post( $a_custom_post, true);
```

How can i do it ?

Comment: `__( 'Foo page name', PLUGIN_DOMAIN )` should work, do you mean the translations are in another language different from the admin's current language? if so, look into [this post](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/11/07/user-admin-languages-and-locale-switching-in-4-7/)

Comment: My administration is in french, the translation exists, but it's store in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution !
The problem was I loaded plugin domain only when plugins are loaded, not for the activation plugin.

It resolves my problem...

**MyPLugin.php**

```
class WPGroupSubs {
    public function __construct(){

        // Install needed components on plugin activation
        /* need to add this */
        register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'load_text_domain' ) ); 
        register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'install' ) );

       //Translation  when plugins are loaded
       add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'load_text_domain' ) );
      ...       
    }

    public function load_text_domain(){
            load_plugin_textdomain( $this->domain, false, plugin_basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/translations' );

    }
}
```